# Difference Between Amazon "Lex & Polly" vs "Alexa Voice services + Alexa skill kit"

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, amazon-polly, amazon-lex

I have recently seen a tutorial where developer created a alexa skill and then installed alexa voice service in raspberry pi and invoked that skill using that voice service. So my Detailed Question is , Can i do the same this using Amazon Lex where User can input speech into the system, Lex is invoked then apply some Amazon Lambda functions for conversation and then uses Amazon polly for converting text to speech inorder to reply to user?

[Amazon Lex](https://aws.amazon.com/lex/?p=tile)

[Alexa Voice Service](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa-voice-service)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

The Alexa services are specific to the Alexa platform. You can create skills but they can only be invoked via an Alexa client (eg Amazon Echo).

Amazon Lex and Amazon Polly give you the building-blocks to create your own voice-based service and do not require integration with the Alexa Voice Services platform.

Your own application can request Amazon Polly to **generate speech** in an mp3 audio and your application can pass an audio file to Amazon Lex to determine intent and user input.